# Run SQLCMD through Batch Script to create a formatted XML file from a stored transaction

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms, sqlcmd

I'm trying to automate the process of running a stored procedure in a database by using SQLCMD. SQL Server Management Studio 2008 is installed on the Windows Server that this is all trying to happen in. SQLCMD will be called through a batch script and told to execute the stored procedure and save the output into an XML file. I cannot show the stored procedure as it has sensitive material, but it includes the usage of FOR XML PATH('').

I read several articles from all kinds of sites and people have said to use :XML ON to get the output in actual XML format and not in tabular format, as well as the switches of "-h-1 -y 0" to make sure that the output isn't truncated. I am trying to run the SQLCMD through a batch script so that it can all be automated.

My current batch script (the variables are all defined before this line in the script):

```
    sqlcmd -X -Q -h-1 -y 0 "EXEC %TransactionName%" -d %Database% -S %ServerInstance% -o "%OutFilename%_%currDATE%.xml"
```

I tried adding :XML ON in the transaction as well as creating a seperate SQL script that reads:

```
    Run_Transact.sql
    :XML ON
    EXEC storedProcedure
```

and so the batch file would then read:

```
    sqlcmd -X -Q -h-1 -y 0 -i runTransact.sql -d %Database% -S %ServerInstance% -o "%OutFilename%_%currDATE%.xml"
```

I get back the error:

HResult 0x80004005, Level 16, State 1
No description provided

If I don't use :XML ON then I get output that looks like it is in tabular format and it includes a header as well as only the first record, but not all of it (it gets truncated).

My question is how can I get the output in the XML file to actually look like XML and not truncated as well?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11143215/27825

Comment: Hi Ed! It seems the link you posted is directed to my question still...I think I've read most of the posts on stackoverflow related to my problem, but if you find one I overlooked I'd be really grateful. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me. I retrieved 2 milion lines xml usinq sqlcmd from xml column. My steps:

1) Create File with query, this is mine:

```
:XML ON
USE <DB_NAME>
SELECT TOP 1 <COLUMN_NAME> FROM <TABLE>
WHERE <SOMETHING>
FOR XML PATH('')
```

2) Execute command in sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -d <DB_NAME> -i <PATH>\query.sql >result.txt
```

And replace what you need in <>

In your case you have stored procedure. Maybe it will cause problems? But you can try something like;

```
USE<DB_NAME>
DECLARE @XMLV XML
EXEC @XMLV = EXEC StoredProcedure
SELECT @XMLV
FOR XML PATH('')
```

I know the question is quite old, but maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ( SELECT 'White' AS Color1,
'Blue' AS Color2,
'Black' AS Color3,
'Light' AS 'Color4/@Special',
'Green' AS Color4,
'Red' AS Color5
FOR
XML PATH('Colors'),
TYPE
),
( SELECT 'Apple' AS Fruits1,
'Pineapple' AS Fruits2,
'Grapes' AS Fruits3,
'Melon' AS Fruits4
FOR
XML PATH('Fruits'),
TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH(''),
ROOT('SampleXML')
GO
```